# Binning collection based on type

Tags: python

I have some items that I need to bucket based on two conditions.

```
items = ['a', 1, 'b', 0.5, 'c', 2, 2.5]
```

Expected output:

```
str_and_ints = ['a', 1, 'b', 'c', 2]
ints = [1, 2]
```

My solution:

```
str_and_ints = [x for x in items if isinstance(x, (str,int))]
ints = [x for x in items if isinstance(x, int)]
```

Is it possible to do this with one generator and unpack the two into their respective collections? Something like this:

```
str_and_ints, ints = ...
```

Comment: Just use a regular loop. Note, you haven't used any generators here... But honestly, your solution *is fine as it is*.

Comment: Or better, use a dict and group by the type

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it's possible, but it's simpler to do a basic for-loop:

```
str_and_ints = []
ints = []
for x in items:
    if isinstance(x, str):
        str_and_ints.append(x)
    elif isinstance(x, int):
        str_and_ints.append(x)
        ints.append(x)
```

Note that with this approach, `isinstance(x, (str,int))` is no longer needed since we can check both types separately.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to do this in a single generator, or frankly in a simpler way than you already have.

Answer (score 0):

You can define variables in lists:

```py
items = ['a', 1, 'b', 0.5, 'c', 2, 2.5]
[str_and_ints,ints] = [[x for x in items if isinstance(x,(str,int))], [x for x in items if isinstance(x,int)]]
```

```
>>> str_and_ints
['a', 1, 'b', 'c', 2]
>>> ints
[1, 2]
```

Comment: tricky one :) you bundled them into one container list :D

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function beforehand:

```
def with_types(items, *types):
    sub_items = []
    for x in items:
        if isinstance(x, types):
            sub_items.append(x)
    return sub_items


items = ['a', 1, 'b', 0.5, 'c', 2, 2.5]
str_and_ints, ints = with_types(items, (str, int)), with_types(items, int)
```

Output

```
>>> str_and_ints
['a', 1, 'b', 'c', 2]
>>> ints
[1, 2]
```

This solution makes the code easily maintainable and readable. You can reuse it too in the future if you need to do similar manipulations.